# Want to group a Covid 19 dataset by continent with pandas but the assumed Visualisation is wrong in Plotly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly, plotly-python

I am very new to all this things and right now im learning Python. I know the basics but right now I have a problem with a covid-19 dataset in which I want to group by continent to get the total death rates of Europe, Asia etc. When I look at the visualisation I only see "Others" and too much lines. Hope you can help me out and tell me what I am doing wrong. Right now I think the problem lies in the for loop.

my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.offline as pyo
import plotly.graph_objs as go

df = pd.read_csv("https://opendata.ecdc.europa.eu/covid19/casedistribution/csv")
df.set_index("continentExp", inplace=True)
del df["countryterritoryCode"], df["Cumulative_number_for_14_days_of_COVID-19_cases_per_100000"], df["geoId"], df["countriesAndTerritories"]

data = []

for name in df.index.unique():
   trace = go.Scatter(
    x = df["dateRep"], 
    y = df["deaths"],
    name = name,
    mode = "lines"
    )
   data.append(trace)

layout = go.Layout(
            title = "Covid-19 Dashboard",
            xaxis = {"title" : "Datum"},
            yaxis = {"title" : "Tote"})

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

pyo.plot(fig)
```

Comment: Hi Mark Haan and welcome on SO. Since version 4.0 plotly is offline only so there is no need to specify it.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me you have a problem with `pandas` rather than with `plotly`. If you are looking for the daily deaths by continent you should use groupby.

## Arrange data

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objs as go

df = pd.read_csv("https://opendata.ecdc.europa.eu/covid19/casedistribution/csv")

# better to have data as datetime
df["dateRep"] = df["dateRep"].astype("M8")
# the previous is equivalent to
# df["dateRep"] = pd.to_datetime(df["dateRep"])

# now you want to look for the daily deaths 
# for every continent
grp = df.groupby(["continentExp","dateRep"])["deaths"]\
        .sum().reset_index()
```

## using `plotly.express`

```py
fig = px.line(grp, 
              x="dateRep", 
              y="deaths", 
              color="continentExp",
              labels={"deaths":"Tote",
                      "dateRep":"Datum"})

fig.update_layout(title="Covid-19 Dashboard",
                  title_x=0.5)
```

[image]

## Using `plotly.graph_objs`

```py
fig = go.Figure()
continents = grp["continentExp"].unique()
for continent in continents:
    ts = grp[grp["continentExp"]==continent]
    fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=ts["dateRep"],
               y=ts["deaths"],
               name=continent))

fig.update_layout(title="Covid-19 Dashboard",
                  title_x=0.5,
                  xaxis={"title" : "Datum"},
                  yaxis={"title" : "Tote"})
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a bunch, really appreciated it! How does the code looks like if I want the cumulative deaths by continent?

Comment: Do you mind to add the error? What plotly version are you using?

Comment: version 4.8.2 and I am getting   --> Key Error "continentExp"